# Rails: Why is this join query failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm wearing thin today so it may be that I'm asking something completely obvious.

I have two models: `Issue` and `Language`. An issue has a language and a language has many issues.

```
    class Language < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :issues
    end

    class Issue < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :language
    end
```

`Issue` has a language id column:

```
    > Issue.column_names
     => ["id", "created_at", "updated_at", "language_id"]
```

`Language` has the following:

```
    > Language.column_names
     => ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

I can create a language row and an issue row pointing to that language successfully.

```
    > lang = Language.create(name: 'hello')
    > Issue.create(language: lang)
    > 
    > Issue.first.language.name
    => "hello"
```

I can find the language row by name:

```
    > Language.find_by(name: 'hello')
    > => #<Language id: 1, name: "hello", created_at: "2019-01-25 16:06:39", updated_at: "2019-01-25 16:06:39">
```

But if I try to use the following join, I'm stuck:

```
     > Issue.joins(:language).where(language: { name: 'hello' })
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: language.name: SELECT  "issues".* FROM "issues" INNER JOIN "languages" ON "languages"."id" = "issues"."language_id" WHERE "language"."name" = ? ORDER BY "issues"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ?)
```

Picking apart the SQL, I assume my query is looking for a language id where the language name matches `'hello'`. But further than that, I'm stuck.

Why is the `join` query failing? Have I written it correctly. Is the problem with the query itself or does it look likely that it's being caused elsewhere?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? It almost seems like you ought to do: `Language.find_by(name: 'hello').issues`, but I'm not quite sure what your goal is. (Apologies if it's obvious.)

Comment: You're right. `Language.find_by(name: 'hello').issues` is faster.

Comment: …but there's a difference that I don't quite understand. I can drop an array of names in the first and it will return all the matches whilst the latter appears only to return the first match. I'm not sure if I've understood it correctly but that's another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use plural form in where condition:

```
> Issue.joins(:language).where(languages: { name: 'hello' })
```

Comment: Yes, I see. `languages` is a reference to the a table not a row.